# plsql count by date and sum up to the date

Tags: plsql

I'd like to have a plsql request that count the number of row by date and the sum of row up to the date.

The source will be somethings like this (hundreds of dates):

```
2019.05.01
2019.05.01
2019.05.02
2019.05.03
2019.05.03
2019.05.03
...
```

and the result:

```
date        nb  sum
-------------------
2019.05.01  2   2
2019.05.02  1   3
2019.05.03  3   6
    . . .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is to use an Aggregate Function as an Analytical function which is what the `SUM(COUNT(dt)) OVER (ORDER BY dt)` in the query below is doing.

```
WITH dates AS
(
  SELECT to_date('2019.05.01', 'YYYY.MM.DD') AS dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT to_date('2019.05.01', 'YYYY.MM.DD') AS dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT to_date('2019.05.02', 'YYYY.MM.DD') AS dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT to_date('2019.05.03', 'YYYY.MM.DD') AS dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT to_date('2019.05.03', 'YYYY.MM.DD') AS dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT to_date('2019.05.03', 'YYYY.MM.DD') AS dt FROM dual
)

SELECT dt, COUNT(dt) AS nb, SUM(COUNT(dt)) OVER (ORDER BY dt) AS sum
FROM dates
GROUP BY dt
;
```

[image]

Comment: I will note that the answer I provided is using standard SQL.  Let me know if for some reason you need this done only in PL/SQL. 
 Without knowing more as to why PL/SQL was originally requested to obtain this data I provided the simplest way to obtain the output requested.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I don't know the list of dates (hundreds)
Do you have a generic solution?

Comment: @user1753180 The solution I provided works with any dates... the list of dates within the CTE (With Block) are just made up dates based on the dates you submitted with your question.  What dates does my solution NOT work with and perhaps we can go from there?  Any date you add to the 'fake data' I provided in the CTE will work.  Again, let me know when my solution is failing and I'll gladly take a look.

Comment: @user1753180 Also, if you are having issues applying my solution to your existing data I can also assist with that.  Perhaps this is where you are having trouble?

Answer (score -1):

First half is relatively easy. Something like

```
SELECT date, count(*) from table GROUP BY date ORDER BY date;
```

But I'm not sure about the cumulative sum. If it's a manual process then I'd probably just import into Excel and do it there to be honest.